# Using C#.NET 4 to read the DOM and click a Submit Image - why, suddenly, do I get an error about casting?

Tags: c#, parsing, .net-4.0, mshtml

I have some code that has been working for me for several months, but today, I am getting casting errors?

I am using the mshtml library to click an adjust input image:

```
mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection objCollection = (mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection)objDocument.getElementsByName("submit");
for (int i = 0; i < objCollection.length; i++)
{
   mshtml.IHTMLElement objElement = (mshtml.IHTMLElement)objCollection.item(i, 0);
   if (objElement.getAttribute("alt") == "adjust")
   {
      // This line below gives me the error.
      mshtml.htmlInputImage objSubmit = (mshtml.htmlInputImage)objElement;
      objSubmit.click();
      bOK = true;
   }
}
```

At the // line above, I get the following message:

> Unable to cast object of type 'mshtml.HTMLInputElementClass' to type
>   'mshtml.htmlInputImage'.

This used to work and this part of the code has not changed. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong and why should this just start to not work? I use this type of structure in other places and all is working...

Comment: Has the the mark-up for the page changed?

Comment: As far as I know, the page has not changed, but that is the sort of thing that I was wondering.

Comment: I think that the version of IE on the machine has been changed and his has broken things. I found another section of code and re-used that code that did almost the same thing and it is now working OK.

Comment: You should post that as the answer and then accept it.  Glad you found a solution to your problem.